# Unique id in OSM data

Tags: openstreetmap, uniqueidentifier

I am using the tool osm2pgsql to import the open street map data in postgresql. Is there any unique identifier for lines, polygons, points so that on the next import i could find and update them?

Comment: You don't have to figure this out on your own, osm2pgsql can also update your database!

Comment: i need to have a unique identifier because i do not use the osm table directly to query for information but i use these tables to extract data and save to my own database tables. So when i import an new file i need to know which to update or to create etc...